# Spring Boot not connecting to Redshift

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, amazon-redshift

Here is how the code looks:

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web", 
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.14", 
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile files("lib/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.1.1001.jar")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:redshift://redshift:5439/pocdb
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=***
```

**Exception thread**

```
Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
    Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@31da6b2e returned null for URL:jdbc:redshift://redshift:5439/pocdb
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:329) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
```

No idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was referring the old postgres driver.